# Perform search for text formatting on last row of text using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have output with many rows. The number of rows on the output is **inconsistent**. Is there a way that the last row can be selected so that a character may be found and replaced? If not using `awk` or `sed`, any `Unix`* tool.

This is a simplified example of the input I need to modify. Typically it would be one to two hundred rows in length and varies. I would like to find the final comma and remove it.

**Example Input**

```
202", # 1233eda 
049", # 1022ats 
194", # 109nunnz 
180", # 0010204NE 
113", # 10195y.it 
489", # 1-420 
345", # 192EelL 
209", # 18tWa 
145", # 18tr 
137", # 1165y_SVM 
561", # 1odeN 
737", # 1hoer_co 
816", # 10138wDUSW 
954", # 1013saLN349ND 
969", # 112t-2_420 
114", # 1012i.fm 
650", # 10zy.i 
860", # 1119b.co 
177", # 1.0109tz
```

**Desired Output**

```
202", # 1233eda 
049", # 1022ats 
194", # 109nunnz 
180", # 0010204NE 
113", # 10195y.it 
489", # 1-420 
345", # 192EelL 
209", # 18tWa 
145", # 18tr 
137", # 1165y_SVM 
561", # 1odeN 
737", # 1hoer_co 
816", # 10138wDUSW 
954", # 1013saLN349ND 
969", # 112t-2_420 
114", # 1012i.fm 
650", # 10zy.i 
860", # 1119b.co 
177"  # 1.0109tz
```

Comment: Define `nix` tool, is it Unix or Nixos? Be precise, thanks

Comment: I just mean nix as in unix. Sorry, not very clear about the definition. I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed '$s/,//' file
```

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `$` | last line of file |
| `s/TO_REPLACE/REMPLACEMENT/` | substitution skeleton |
| `,` | literal ',' |

With a `Perl`'s one-liner:

```
$ perl -F, -ne 'if (eof()) {print join " ", @F} else {print}' file
```

##### Output

```
202", # 1233eda 
049", # 1022ats 
194", # 109nunnz 
180", # 0010204NE 
113", # 10195y.it 
489", # 1-420 
345", # 192EelL 
209", # 18tWa 
145", # 18tr 
137", # 1165y_SVM 
561", # 1odeN 
737", # 1hoer_co 
816", # 10138wDUSW 
954", # 1013saLN349ND 
969", # 112t-2_420 
114", # 1012i.fm 
650", # 10zy.i 
860", # 1119b.co 
177"  # 1.0109tz
```

Comment: Thanks this answer gave me the desired output. If I could just ask one querstion: In the sed solution, why does the substitution skeleton need two backslashes after the literal?

Comment: Because `//` mean 'nothing'. `s/to replace/replaced/`

Comment: Thanks, I've got the syntax now. Grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you have to do with that input then I'd use the sed solution that [@Gilles posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743086/133219) but since you already have `sed` and `perl` scripts and in case you actually need to do more than that, here's one way to do it in `awk` by just buffering 1 line:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print p} {p=$0} END{sub(/,/," ",p); print p}' file
202", # 1233eda
049", # 1022ats
194", # 109nunnz
180", # 0010204NE
113", # 10195y.it
489", # 1-420
345", # 192EelL
209", # 18tWa
145", # 18tr
137", # 1165y_SVM
561", # 1odeN
737", # 1hoer_co
816", # 10138wDUSW
954", # 1013saLN349ND
969", # 112t-2_420
114", # 1012i.fm
650", # 10zy.i
860", # 1119b.co
177"  # 1.0109tz
```